# register_shutdown_function overwrite

Tags: php, function

Is it possible to overwrite the already set `register_shutdown_function` stack? Something like:

```
function f1(){
    echo "f1";
}
function f2(){
    echo "f2";
}
register_shutdown_function("f1");
echo "actions here";
register_shutdown_function("f2");
call_to_undefined_function(); // to "produce" the error
```

In this case I want the script to only call `f2()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. PHP has a [`remove_user_shutdown_function`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/basic_functions.c#remove_user_shutdown_function) PHPAPI function, but this is not exposed to userland code.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it straight, but there's always a workaround:

```
$first = register_cancellable_shutdown_function(function () {
    echo "This function is never called\n";
});

$second = register_cancellable_shutdown_function(function () {
    echo "This function is going to be called\n";
});

cancel_shutdown_function($first);
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php
This function is going to be called
```

[The code](https://gist.github.com/sanmai/f271b89cf306634ba123):

```
function register_cancellable_shutdown_function($callback)
{
        return new cancellable_shutdown_function_envelope($callback);
}

function cancel_shutdown_function($envelope)
{
    $envelope->cancel();
}

final class cancellable_shutdown_function_envelope
{
        private $callback;

        public function __construct($callback)
        {
                $this->callback = $callback;
                register_shutdown_function(function () {
                        $this->callback && call_user_func($this->callback);
                });
        }

        public function cancel()
        {
                $this->callback = false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from the [php doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) on `register_shutdown_function()`:

> Multiple calls to register_shutdown_function() can be made, and each
>   will be called in the same order as they were registered. If you call
>   exit() within one registered shutdown function, processing will stop
>   completely and no other registered shutdown functions will be called.

so this means that if you want to only call function `f2` you can pass it in to an exit() call in an exception handler. Multiple calls to `register_shutdown_function()` will call all of the functions in order, not just the last registered. Since there doesn't seem to be any sort of `unregister_shutdown_function()` this is what I suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Other option is to use the following function:

```
function register_named_shutdown_function($name, $callback)
{
        static $callbacks = [];
        $callbacks[$name] = $callback;

        static $registered;
        $registered || $registered = register_shutdown_function(function () use (&$callbacks) {
                array_map(function ($callback) {
                        call_user_func($callback);
                }, $callbacks);
        }) || true;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
register_named_shutdown_function("first", function () {
        echo "Never executed\n";
});

register_named_shutdown_function("second", function () {
        echo "Secondly executed\n";
});

register_named_shutdown_function("first", function () {
        echo "Firstly executed\n";
});
```

Outputs:

```
Firstly executed
Secondly executed
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, and I resolved this as:

```
function f1(){
if (defined('CALL1') && CALL1===false) return false;
echo "f1";
}
function f2(){
    echo "f2";
}
register_shutdown_function("f1");
echo "actions here";
define('CALL1', false);
register_shutdown_function("f2");
call_to_undefined_function();
```