# PHP register_shutdown_function() execution order change

Tags: php, shutdown, order-of-execution

I have few functions registered with register_shutdown_function() in different places of the code.

As I know by default they are executed in the same order as they were registered. Can I change this order somehow after functions registered?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431843/register-shutdown-function-overwrite) can help you out? Senmai's answer seems interesting for something simular to your problem.